# Pop up User Control in a new Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

Any help will do!

I have a C# GUI which contain a User Control, this User Control contains a web browser, I want to make a button which will make it pop in a new window in the current state it is in.

Lets say I have the web browser opened on a specific page in Google, and I want to pop up the User Control in a new Windows Form at the same state and not as a new window that will take me to google.com but to the current page I had open.

Is there anyway to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you passing the desired URL from main form to the new form having the user control ?

Comment: @PiyushParashar I don't mean to copy it as the url, I want to open it in the exact state, if I wrote something in a text box I want it to just expand in a new window, like if I resize a window of like Chrome or something like that, make it full screen in a new window. hope this explains my means well.

Comment: Well then maybe don't close the form with usercontrol and browser. Just hide/show when required so that it will maintain the details. Does that make sense?

Comment: please post the code that you've tried

Comment: @PiyushParashar I don't want to close it I want to be able to transfer it

Comment: @paqogomez There is no code to it yet, I have a User Control, a button and a new Windows Form I just need to know if a way to do what I want to do exist, to take what is present in the User Control at the moment and make it appear in a new Form.

Comment: You might be able to pass the instance of the webbrowser to your form, but that sounds very kludgy.

Comment: @paqogomez Kludgy or not if it is possible and working, I will gladly hear your way!

Comment: I throw out the idea, you implement it if it works for you.  You havent posted enough information to do anything more.

Comment: @paqogomez http://www.mediafire.com/download/te93wn0jf2xkkoo/WindowsFormsApplication1.rar
This should show you pretty much what should be in this GUI, the button will pop up the UserControl in a new Window Form but I think you understand what I want it to do, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

a) Access the UserControl class from the parent forms class.

b) Create a internal property in user control class that will return your WebBrowser control object.

c) From the main form you can then access WebBrowser.Url property and you either save this URL, redirect the browser or save the URL to show the user control later with the same URL. If you assign a string to this Url property it will navigate the browser to that page.

Please read this [WebBrowser.Url MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I commented to you that copying the URL isn't going to help me what I need is to copy the User Control itself as it is at a moment of copying it to a new Form, I though of just opening the User Control in a new Form as well but it isn't what I truly need.